# Why is trying to store a pointer to function ambiguous

Tags: c++, function, c++11

Here is my code:

```
    #include <functional>
    #include <iostream>
    #include<vector>

    using namespace std;

    // vector iterator
    template <class T> class vit
    {
            private:
            //vector<T>::iterator it;
            vector<T> m_v;
            function<bool (T, T)> m_fptr;
            int len, pos;
            public:
            vit(vector<T> &v) { this->m_v = v; len = v.size(); pos = 0;};
           //       it= v.begin(); };
            bool next(T &i) {
                    //if(it == m_v.end()) return false;
                    if(pos==len) return false;
                    //i = *it;
                    i = m_v[pos];
                    //if(idle) { idle = false ; return true; }
                    //it++;
                    pos++;
                    return true;};
            //bool idle = true;
            void set_same(function<bool (T,T)> fptr) { m_fptr = fptr ;};
            //void set_same(function<bool(int, int)> fun) { return ; }
            bool grp_begin() {
                    return pos == 0 || ! m_fptr(m_v[pos], m_v[pos-1]); };
            bool grp_end() {
                    return pos == len || ! m_fptr(m_v[pos], m_v[pos+1]); };
    };


    bool is_same(int a, int b) { return a == b; }

    main()
    {
            vector<int>  v ={ 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1 };
            int total;
            for(auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) {
                    if(it == v.begin() || *it != *(it-1)) {
                            total = 0;
                    }

                    total += *it;

                    if(it+1 == v.end() || *it != *(it+1)) {
                            cout << total << endl;
                    }
            }

            cout << "let's gry a group" <<endl;
            vit<int> g(v);
            int i;
            while(g.next(i)) { cout << i << endl; }

            cout << "now let's get really fancy" << endl;
            vit<int> a_vit(v);
            //auto is_same = [](int a, int b) { return a == b; };
            a_vit.set_same(is_same);
            //int total;
            while(a_vit.next(i)) {
                    if(a_vit.grp_begin()) total = 0;
                    total += i;
                    if(a_vit.grp_end()) cout << total << endl ;
            }
    }
```

When I compile it with g++ -std=c++11 iter.cc -o iter, I get the result:

```
    iter.cc: In function 'int main()':
    iter.cc:63:17: error: reference to 'is_same' is ambiguous
      a_vit.set_same(is_same);
             ^
    iter.cc:37:6: note: candidates are: bool is_same(int, int)
     bool is_same(int a, int b) { return a == b; }
          ^
    In file included from /usr/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/move.h:57:0,
                     from /usr/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                     from /usr/include/c++/5.3.0/utility:70,
                     from /usr/include/c++/5.3.0/tuple:38,
                     from /usr/include/c++/5.3.0/functional:55,
                     from iter.cc:1:
    /usr/include/c++/5.3.0/type_traits:958:12: note:                         template<class, class> struct std::is_same
         struct is_same;
                ^
```

By way of explanation, I have created a class called 'vit'. It does two things: iterate over a vector, and determine if a new group has been reached.

The class function 'set_same' is supposed to store a function provided by the calling class to determine if two adjacent elements of a vector are in the same group. However, I can't seem to store the function in the class for future use by grp_begin() and grp_end() on account of the ostensible ambiguity of is_same.

What gives?

Comment: Could you clean this up? Very hard to read your code.

Comment: Why has someone downvoted all of the answers?

Comment: Okay now the downvotes have been removed from everyone's but mine... the only one that actually provides a solution. Something very suspicious going on here.

Comment: You might consider flagging the question so the moderators can look into it.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I thought about it, but it's not egregious enough to warrant their time. Just annoying.

Answer (score 5):

There is an `is_same` function defined by you and there is a struct `is_same` defined [by the C++ Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same). Since you are `using namespace std`, your compiler doesn't know which `is_same` you meant to use.

Answer (score 3):

It's what the error says: it's not clear whether you mean *your* `is_same` (in the global namespace) or [the class template `is_same` (in namespace `std`)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same).

You may disambiguate as follows:

```
::is_same
```

… with the leading `::` meaning "in the global namespace".

Though you should consider putting your code in a namespace of its own.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. This is my first time touching C++ after more than a decade. I have cleaned up the code, and used a lambda to bring the "is_same" function closer to where it is called.

Did you spot the bug in my code? 'pos' was off-by-one when calling grp_begin() and grp_end(). Here is the revised code:

```
    #include <functional>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>


    // vector iterator
    template <class T> class vit
    {
            private:
                    std::vector<T> m_v;
                    std::function<bool (T, T)> m_fptr;
                    int len, pos;
            public:
                    vit(std::vector<T> &v) { m_v = v; len = v.size();         pos = -1;};
                    bool next(T &val) {
                            pos++;
                            if(pos==len) return false;
                            val = m_v[pos];
                            return true;};
                    void set_same(std::function<bool (T,T)> fptr)         {         m_fptr = fptr ;};
                    bool grp_begin() {
                            return pos == 0 || ! m_fptr(m_v[pos],         m_v[pos-1]); };
                    bool grp_end() {
                            return pos+1 == len || ! m_fptr(m_v[pos], m_v[pos+1]); };
    };





    main()
    {
            std::vector<int>  v ={ 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1 };
            vit<int> a_vit(v);
            std::function<bool (int, int)> is_same = [](int a, int b) { return a == b; };
            a_vit.set_same(is_same);
            int i, total;
            while(a_vit.next(i)) {
                    if(a_vit.grp_begin()) total = 0;
                    total += i;
                    if(a_vit.grp_end()) std::cout << total << std::endl ;
            }
    }
```

My class definition isn't bullet-proof and could be better: if the user forgets to 'set-same', for example, they'll be referring a random memory address as a function.

Nevertheless, I'm pretty chuffed with my solution so far. The class caller is relieved of all the bookkeeping relating iterating over the vector, and working out if a group boundary has been crossed.

The calling code looks very compact and intuitive to me.I can see C++ being my go to language.